# Issue while try to update previously published pine script

Tags: pine-script

I can't update my previously published pine script and it is not showing in the community script also could you tell me the reason

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not customer service :) Please create a support ticket on Tradingview.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.